# The abelianization of the derived subgroup of SL(2, Z / N Z).

Tags: gr.group-theory

It is known that the abelianization of $\Gamma : = SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (i.e. $\Gamma / \Gamma^{(1)}$) is $\mathbb{Z} / 12 \mathbb{Z}$. This implies that $|SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z}) / SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^{(1)}| \leq 12 $ (for all $N$). It also appears that the order of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^{(1)} / SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / N \mathbb{Z})^{(2)}$ is bounded independently of $N$ by 12, but this seems more difficult to prove since $\Gamma^{(1)} \cong F(a,b)$ (the free group on two generators) and $|F(a,b) / F(a,b)^{(1)}|$ is infinite. Any ideas as to how to go about proving the above?

Comment: Hint: You can reduce this to the case that $N$ is a prime power using the Chinese remainder theorem. 

Comment: Thanks - so $N=p^n$ for $p \geq 5$ seems ok, but how about when 
$p=2,3$?

Comment: In fact, to be more precise, exactly what I would like to be able to show is:
For all $n \geq 2$: $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 2^n \mathbb{Z})^{(1)} / SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 2^n \mathbb{Z})^{(2)} \cong \mathbb{Z} / 3 \mathbb{Z}$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 3^n \mathbb{Z})^{(1)} / SL_2(\mathbb{Z} / 3^n \mathbb{Z})^{(2)} \cong \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} / 2 \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: You can do this easily by computer calculation for moderately small $n$, so you just need to show that it stabilizes as $n$ increases, which shouldn't be too hard.